# Accessing left child or right child of a node in avl_set

Tags: c++, boost

I know that `std::set` is a balanced tree, and standard C++ forbids accessing the children of a node in `std::set`, But I was wondering if one can access the children and parent of a node in an `avl_set` in *boost* library. If its not possible, Is there any reliable libraries like *boost* that contains self balanced trees that allows such actions?

Comment: A [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is "***usually*** implemented as red-black trees" (emphasis mine). The standard doesn't say anything about the container implementations.

Comment: And if you need more control over the data structure, like access to interior nodes or some special kind of traversal rules, then you need to implement it your self.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Iv implemented a red-black tree and it works just fine. But I was wondering if I could find a code that is more optimized than mine. My program does some heavy computations so a slight change in the performance of my tree can have huge effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, boost contains an avl tree implementation (and some variants of it, IIRC).

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/intrusive/avl_set_multiset.html#intrusive.avl_set_multiset.avl_set_multiset_hooks

That is part of of the Boost Intrusive library. The semantics of this library can be a bit unusual if you're used to regular (standard library) containers.

In fact the library comes with many competing tree algorithms, that you can switch by selecting a different template argument type. See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/intrusive/node_algorithms.html

---

Also note that Intrusive Containers are - by there very nature - very open. You can inspect the node hooks, or, in fact, replace them with your [custom value traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/intrusive/value_traits.html) which brings the pointer layout completely under your control.

Comment: @MoNo it's quite a lot of work. You could see it as implementing your own tree implementation, but using lego bricks (so it's far easier than from scratch)

Comment: As you advised I'm trying to implement it by my own. But I'm stuck. Iv posted a question but it seems that no one is interested in it. It would be great if you could take a look at it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31557312/how-to-access-the-root-of-rbtree-in-boost

Comment: 5 hours is not "no interest". It just means people with the expertise/interest have other things to do. Even I sleep 4 hours a day. It makes sense when you think of it.