# Difference between insert_equal_upper_bound and insert_equal_lower_bound

Tags: boost

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262056/accessing-left-child-or-right-child-of-a-node-in-avl-set) post I'm trying to implement a `red-black tree` using *Boost* library. The example in [this](http:////Now%20insert%20node%20%22two%22%20in%20the%20tree%20using%20the%20sorting%20functor%20%20%20%20algo::insert_equal_upper_bound(&header,%20&two,%20node_ptr_compare());%20%20%20%20%20//Now%20insert%20node%20%22three%22%20in%20the%20tree%20using%20the%20sorting%20functor%20%20%20%20algo::insert_equal_lower_bound(&header,%20&three,%20node_ptr_compare());) page uses two different functions in order to insert a node in the tree. The functions looks like this:

```
//Now insert node "two" in the tree using the sorting functor
algo::insert_equal_upper_bound(&header, &two, node_ptr_compare());

//Now insert node "three" in the tree using the sorting functor
algo::insert_equal_lower_bound(&header, &three, node_ptr_compare());
```

I checked [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/rbtree_algorithms.html#idp71133120-bb) for more information and I realize that there is an `insert_equal` too that looks like this:

```
template<typename NodePtrCompare> 
static node_ptr 
    insert_equal(const node_ptr & header, const node_ptr & hint, 
              const node_ptr & new_node, NodePtrCompare comp);
```

And here is the description for these three functions:

**insert_equal_upper_bound:** Inserts new_node into the tree before the upper bound according to "comp".

**insert_equal_lower_bound:** Inserts new_node into the tree before the lower bound according to "comp".

**insert_equal:** Inserts new_node into the tree, using "hint" as a hint to where it will be inserted. If "hint" is the upper_bound the insertion takes constant time (two comparisons in the worst case).

But I don't understand the difference between these three functions. isn't Red-Black tree a (almost)balanced tree? Will it remain balanced after using these functions to insert a node? Which one should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all of these will (modulo bugs) maintain the balance of the tree.

Ignore for the moment the tree structure, however, and it'll be easier to understand what they do. Consider it as just a simple linear collection of items like:

```
1 3 3 6 6 7 8 8 9
```

Now let's assume you're going to insert another `8` into the collection. If you use `insert_equal_lower_bound`, it'll insert the new `8` *before* any of the `8`s that's already in the collection.

If you use either `insert_equal_upper_bound` or `insert_equal`, the new `8` will be inserted *after* the last `8` that's already in the collection. The difference here is that `insert_equal` allows you to specify a "hint" about where you think the insertion will take place--and if that hint is correct, you get amortized constant complexity for insertions (rather that logarithmic complexity you get without a hint).

Comment: Thanks a lot. But what about the header? is it the root of the tree? can it be changed while inserting new data? if it doesn't how can I access the root of my tree? In the descriptions it said that " the header node is maintained with links not only to the root but also . . ." But it doesn't say how to access the root.