# How to access the root of rbtree in boost

Tags: boost

Iv implemented a red-black tree based on [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/intrusive/node_algorithms.html#intrusive.node_algorithms.rbtree_algorithms) example. But I don't understand the meaning of the header, is it the root of the tree? according to the descriptions:

> the header node is maintained with links not only to the root but also to the leftmost node of the tree, to enable constant time begin(), and to the rightmost node of the tree, to enable linear time performance when used with the generic set algorithms (set_union, etc.);

How can I access the root of my tree using header node? and what is the complexity of that?

Comment: "Iv implemented a red-black tree" // You should probably share the code

Comment: Well, My code is just like the one in the example. I just added some more details to it.My problem is that I don't know if header has a link to the root or I should specify it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header node in Boost Intrusive's RBTree implementations contains the link to the root, leftmost and rightmost nodes (see [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost/intrusive/rbtree_algorithms.html)).

So, `parent_` is the pointer to the root node then.

You can use a container abstraction *based on* the "algorithm policy" shown in that example. You'd write [custom value traits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/intrusive/value_traits.html), like I linked in my previous answer: [Accessing left child or right child of a node in avl_set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31262056/accessing-left-child-or-right-child-of-a-node-in-avl-set/31264152#31264152)

Here's a simple, self-contained example that shows how to use an actual `rbtree` container (not just the algorithms) built on your node type.

Note how you can still "drill through" and get at the nodes using the containers traits.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cacf6f5fc334fba7)</kbd>**

```
struct my_node
{
    my_node(int i = 0) :
        parent_(nullptr),
        left_  (nullptr),
        right_ (nullptr),
        int_   (i)
    { }

    my_node *parent_, *left_, *right_;
    int      color_;
    //data members
    int      int_;

    bool operator<(my_node const& other) const { return int_ < other.int_; }
};

//Define our own rbtree_node_traits
struct my_rbtree_node_traits
{
   typedef my_node                                    node;
   typedef my_node *                                  node_ptr;
   typedef const my_node *                            const_node_ptr;
   typedef int                                        color;
   static node_ptr get_parent(const_node_ptr n)       {  return n->parent_;   }
   static void set_parent(node_ptr n, node_ptr parent){  n->parent_ = parent; }
   static node_ptr get_left(const_node_ptr n)         {  return n->left_;     }
   static void set_left(node_ptr n, node_ptr left)    {  n->left_ = left;     }
   static node_ptr get_right(const_node_ptr n)        {  return n->right_;    }
   static void set_right(node_ptr n, node_ptr right)  {  n->right_ = right;   }
   static color get_color(const_node_ptr n)           {  return n->color_;    }
   static void set_color(node_ptr n, color c)         {  n->color_ = c;       }
   static color black()                               {  return color(0);     }
   static color red()                                 {  return color(1);     }
};

#include <boost/intrusive/link_mode.hpp>
namespace bi = boost::intrusive;

struct my_value_traits
{
   typedef my_rbtree_node_traits        node_traits;
   typedef node_traits::node            value_type;
   typedef node_traits::node_ptr        node_ptr;
   typedef node_traits::const_node_ptr  const_node_ptr;
   typedef value_type*                  pointer;
   typedef value_type const*            const_pointer;

   static const bi::link_mode_type link_mode = bi::link_mode_type::normal_link;

   static node_ptr       to_node_ptr    (value_type &value)       { return &value; } 
   static const_node_ptr to_node_ptr    (const value_type &value) { return &value; } 
   static pointer        to_value_ptr   (node_ptr n)              { return n;      } 
   static const_pointer  to_value_ptr   (const_node_ptr n)        { return n;      } 
};

#include <boost/intrusive/rbtree.hpp>
using mytree = bi::rbtree<my_node, bi::value_traits<my_value_traits> >;

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<my_node> storage { {1}, {3}, {4}, {2}, {3}, };

    mytree container;
    container.insert_equal(storage.begin(), storage.end());

    // NOW for the "have your cake and eat it too" moment:
    for (my_node& n : container) {
        std::cout << n.int_ 
            << " (parent: " << n.parent_ << ")"
            << " (left:   " << n.left_ << ")"
            << " (right:  " << n.right_ << ")"
            << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints (e.g.):

```
1 (parent: 0xb01c40) (left:   0) (right:  0xb01c80)
2 (parent: 0xb01c20) (left:   0) (right:  0)
3 (parent: 0x7fff6da3f058) (left:   0xb01c20) (right:  0xb01c60)
3 (parent: 0xb01c60) (left:   0) (right:  0)
4 (parent: 0xb01c40) (left:   0xb01ca0) (right:  0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The structure of a Boost.Intrusive tree is explained in the documentation of bstree_algorithms (http://www.boost.org/boost/intrusive/bstree_algorithms.hpp). The "header" node is also explained:

*"At the top of the tree a node is used specially. This node's parent pointer is pointing to the root of the tree. Its left pointer points to the leftmost node in the tree and the right pointer to the rightmost one. This node is used to represent the end-iterator."*

So you can access the root node using:

```
root = rbtree_algorithms::get_parent(header);
```

If you are building your own container using value traits, as explained by sehe, since commit:

https://github.com/boostorg/intrusive/commit/bbb4f724d037a6ab5ee0d9bde292f0691564960c

tree-based containers have a root() function that returns an iterator to the root node (or end() if not present) with O(1) complexity, which might be easier to use:

```
#include <boost/intrusive/set.hpp>
#include <cassert>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

struct MyClass : public set_base_hook<>
{
   friend bool operator<(const MyClass&, const MyClass&)
   {  return true;   }
};

int main()
{
   set<MyClass> set;
   //end() is returned when the tree is empty
   assert(set.root()  == set.end() );

   //insert myobject, must be root
   MyClass myobject;
   set.insert(myobject);
   assert(&*set.root() == &myobject);

   //erase and check root is again end()
   set.erase(set.root());
   assert(set.croot() == set.cend());

   return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Can you be a clearer on what your answer adds that isn't in my answer? I think you left out some words too (what commit?)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I was trying to explain a little more what the root node was (first question) and adding that a recent commit allows obtaining directly the root node from an intrusive container (an alternative to the second question) and the O(1) complexity of that operation (third question). I've edited the answer to include the missing words and link.

Comment: Thanks. That's a valuable addition!